# Ultegra 6800 front hub plastic cover loose

Tags: wheels, shimano, hub

The plastic cover on the right side of my Ultegra 6800 front hub (red circle in the photo) is loose and rotates freely independent of the hub.

Is it normal ? If not how can I clamp it back?

[image]

Comment: Whats underneath?   I have a cover on my alfine hub that has a centerlock disk brake rotor mount, which I don't need and can't use, so leave it covered with the rubber lid provided.

Answer (score 2):

The plastic cover is there to protect the wheel bearings.
It prevents dust from entering in.
So it's totally fine if it's loose.